# Why aren't my morning glories sprouting this year?

Tags: seeds, germination, vines, morning-glory

Every year I plant morning glories from fresh seeds, in containers (the long, rectangular kind).  They always take a bit of time (1-2 weeks) to sprout, and after that, really take off (I hang some twine on the walls of my terrace and they climb up like crazy).

This year, I planted more seeds than I ever have - different varieties of morning glories, as well as some moon flowers.  I soaked the seeds overnight as I always do (for about 24 hours, and I'd say the seeds double, if not triple in size).  Planted them as I always do (about a 1/4" deep as per the directions), in a "zigzag" pattern in the planters, about 4" or so apart.  Probably about 40 seeds in total.

3 weeks later, only 2 have broken through the soil, and even those are not looking so good (very "wrinkly" and weak-looking).  No sign of the others.  I've been watering regularly, and the weather seems about the same as it always (maybe a few nights that have been colder than average).

Basically I've done exactly the same thing that I've done for years, and it's not working for some reason this year.  Any ideas what could be wrong, or what I could to improve the process?  I just planted a whole new batch of seeds (in the same planters) a few days ago.

EDIT:  I should add - I'm in New York City, and the plants get tons of sun.

Comment: if you're doing everything the same maybe it is the quality of the seeds.  I have too many morning glories - they took over in parts of my yard...  they keep reseeding themselves.

Comment: When you planted the new batch did you get new soil?

Comment: @Tim I don't know, I guess it's possible but I buy the seeds by the packet each year, I know I bought them at the same place in the past, and they may even be the same brand...

Comment: @unclebrad The new batch a few days ago?  No, I just stuck them into the existing planters.  This was brand new soil this year (though most years in the past I simply recycled the soil and cleaned out the roots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morning glories HATE cold. Do not attempt to germinate the seeds in an environment with temperatures under 60 on a sustained basis. The seeds will simply rot.

@tim: do not allow morning glories to self-seed.  They revert to useless forms.

Comment: Ah, ok.  It must be the cold.  It's been in the 40s and 50s every night (and many days) recently, but it should be warmer.  How long would it take for them to rot?  Essentially, it *should* be above 60 now, and probably will start to be 60 every day at any time.  At what point do I have to start over?  Roughly how many sub-60 days (or will just nights do it?) will ruin them?

Comment: It varies. It is annoyingly common for us to have late cool snaps here with a streak of nights in the 40s.  That can be lethal to seeds that are just germinating.

Comment: Agreed about them reverting.

Answer (score 1):

I've always let my morning glories reseed.  For years, they come back just as beautiful as the year before.  I'd just give it some more time for the warmer weather to stick around

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the new soil as well. Morning Glories prefer poor soil that is slightly acidic. I live in the Southeast in zone 7a. I have never had a problem with letting many of the common morning glories self seed (except for the tropical varieties like Moonflower, which tend to rot). When they find a place they like, the common, tievine, small, and wild bindweed morning glories grow like wildfire here and take over yards. That is unless the birds eat the seeds while you're not looking, in which case you will find a seed pod with no seeds, half a seed pod with no seeds or no seed pod at all. It may be too cold for them to self seed up there, but I say give it a try... Or, collect the seeds, store in a dry location, then do about 60 days of cold moist stratification, and replant when you know temperatures won't get lower than 45 degrees. Start them in a pot indoors, and then set them outside in the late Spring or Summer. If you're buying new soil, I would recommend using a mix of half topsoil and have garden soil It could also be the new soil as well. Morning Glories prefer poor soil that is well-draining and slightly acidic. I live in the Southeast in zone 7a. They love growing on rock piles, and I have even seen them in solid red clay dirt. I have never had a problem with letting many of the common morning glories self seed (except for the tropical varieties like Moonflower, which don't like how I plant them at all. Lol).

When they find a place they like, the common, tievine, dwarf, and wild bindweed morning glories grow like wildfire here and take over yards. That is unless the birds eat the seeds while you're not looking, in which case you will find a seed pod with no seeds, half a seed pod with no seeds or no seed pod at all. It may be too cold for them to self seed up there, but I say give it a try... Or, collect the seeds once the seed pod is brown and dried, store in a dark and dry location, then do about 60 days of cold moist stratification, and replant when you know temperatures won't get lower than 45 degrees. Start them in a pot indoors, and then set them outside in the late Spring or Summer.

Again, the tropical morning glories (Moonflower and Elephant Creeper) don't like me, so this is just for the others... If you're buying new soil, I would recommend using a mix of 1 part topsoil to 1 part basic garden soil with perlite added (in whatever quantity is recommended on the package). Google how to make your soil slightly acidic, and do this as well. I believe all it takes is a bit of vinegar or unused coffee grounds, but it can be done relatively inexpensively. Hope this helps!

Good luck!